# How to make script that only will run when the player joins for the first time?(roblox)

Tags: roblox

So basically I need to make a script, and when the player joins the game for the first time, script will activate only once and then never again. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

```lua
local Users, DataService = game:GetService("Players"), game:GetService("DataStoreService")
local Store = DataService:GetDataStore("IsPlayerNew") -- we make a store storing if they played already or not.

Users.PlayerAdded:Connect(function(User) -- this is when they join!
    local HasJoined = Store:GetAsync(User.UserId) -- DataStoreService (DSS) uses keys to store data. Using the player's userid makes all keys unique and won't mess with the code!
    if HasJoined then return end -- this will stop the code if they already joined the game before!
    Store:SetAsync(User.UserId, true) -- if this data exists when they next join then it will stop the code. but since it does exist it will then add a value(s) for next time.
end)
```

Storing data is important for a lot of reasons which is why a lot of simulators use it! :O (it can be used to save progress on your favourite puzzle game too).
I hope this helped you and if it did mark the answer as the answer that helped you! IF you need an explanation I'll be happy to :)

Comment: You should probably wrap the `SetAsync` in a pcall and handle errors if it ever happens.

Comment: @Keilorus that's right! though I didn't do it here because he never asked for this, he simply asked on how to do it.